# Convergence in $L^1$ example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, pointwise-convergence

Let the sample space be $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesegue measure.

$$
X_n(w) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{for $ 0\le w \le 1-\frac {1}{n}$ } \\
n, & \text{otherwise } \\
\end{cases}
$$
It surely converges a.s. to 1.
Does the following converges in $L^1$? I don't think so. It looks like to me that $lim \rightarrow E[|X_n-1|]=1$. Am I correct?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed right. The random variable $\left\lvert X_n-1\right\rvert$ takes the value $0$ with probability $1-1/n$, and the value $n-1$ with probability $1/n$ hence 
$\mathbb E\left[\left\lvert X_n-1\right\rvert\right]=(n-1)/n$, which converges to $1$, as said in the opening post. Maybe add a sentence, that if there is a convergence in $L^1$, then it is necessarily to the almost sure limit.

Comment: Thank you. There is a typo in your answer when you say it converges to 0, while it should be one, as clearly emerges from what you wrote. Regarding your last sentence, if a sequence of r.v.s. converges a.s. to a r.v. X, then if there is convergence in $L^1$, it must be to the a.s. limit. It can not be to some other R.V.?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. For your question, yes it is true.